# If $X$ is T1 with a non-empty finite open subset, does $X$ have isolated points?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a $T1$ topological space. Call $x\in X$ isolated point if $\{x\}$ is open in $X$.

Assume there is an open, finite subset $\emptyset \ne V \subseteq X$. Does $X$ admit an isolated point?

If necessary, I can assume that $X$ is compact, Hausdorff and extremally disconnected (the closure of every open is again open) (this is the case in the scenario where I need it).

**Attempt**: I feel like I should somehow be able to prove that $V$ contains an isolated point. I also have the impression that I'm missing something obvious.

Let $U$ be a minimal open subset of $V$ that is open in $V$. Since $V$ is finite and $X$ is $T1$, we have that $G:=U^c \cap V$ is open. Hence, $V = U \cup G$. Somehow I want to show that $U$ is a singelton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, all points of $V$ are isolated in $X$. $V$ with the subspace topology is a finite T1 space and therefore it is a discrete topological space. Therefore $\{x\}$ is open in $V$ for all $x\in V$. Since $V$ is open and $\{x\}$ is open in $V$, $\{x\}$ is open in $X$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in V$ then $F:=V\setminus \{x\}$ is finite (as a subset of $V$) and so closed (as $X$ is $T_1$). So $\{x\} = V\cap (X\setminus F)$ is open in $X$ and so $x$ is isolated.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Make use of the $T1$ property. If $x$ and $y$ are two points in $U$, then you can find an open neighbourhood of $x$ which doesn't contain $y$. Can you contradict minimality with this?